# asked for a solution didn't got any one of them

Tags: support

I don't understand I have asked for help because none of the multiboot usb creator is recognizing my usb drive and for solution and despite being an expert nobody is helping me . I used a solution of one other members who gave it to another person and i used that too . But that didn't solved my problem . Really ??? At somebody would probably give me a right direction to my problem solution but nobody does . Why ? asking myself this question all these days .

Comment: Please add the question you are talking about to this post. We don't know what you mean otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

I assume you are referring to [I have problems when mounting my USB drive in a nonstandard location](https://askubuntu.com/q/671744/85695). First of all, you only asked this yesterday! Have a little patience :)

Then, it is hard to understand what you mean:

> My usb drive gets mounted under /media/username but i tried using umount to mount under /media/usbdisk

You can't use `umount` to mount something, only to unmount it. What is the actual command you ran?

> when I used multisystem multiboot usb creator it doesn't recognize my usb under /media

You used it to do what? How does it not recognize it? Was there an error? Could you add a screenshot showing it? In any case, it probably looks for the default locataion, why did you change it?

Basically, please edit your question, explain exactly what you tried and exactly how it failed including any error messages. Ideally, add the information I asked for here, including a screenshot showing the problem.

In general, questions that are hard to understand don't get answered because people just move on to the next one. To increase your chances of getting an answer, you should always try and make your question as clear and as detailed as possible.

Comment: Sorry my bad ! I just fixed it . It happened because I Haven't formatted it after installing ubuntu 14.04 . I just formatted it with gnome disk utility and that fixed my problem  :)